# Correlation of two images by Haskell 'hip' library (LoG filter)

Tags: r, haskell, image-processing

The [`logFilter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-Processing-Filter.html#v:logFilter) in the 'hip' Haskell library is obtained with the help of the [`correlate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-Processing.html#v:correlate) function. When I apply this filter to this image:

[image]

then I obtain this image:

[image]

I tried to reproduce it in R with the **imager** package and no way to get this result: I tried several ways which all gave a gray image. I tried with the built-in methods and I also tried manually, roughly:

```r
for(r in 1:512) {
  for(c in 1:512){
    red[r, c] <- gre[r, c] <- blu[r, c] <- 0
    for(u in 1:9){
      for(v in 1:9) {
        red[r, c] <- red[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * RED[r+u, c+v]
        gre[r, c] <- gre[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * GRE[r+u, c+v]
        blu[r, c] <- blu[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * BLU[r+u, c+v]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

up to the problem with the borders.

I don't completely understand the code of `correlate`, in particular I don't understand what the [`toManifest`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-Interface.html#v:toManifest) function does. What does `toManifest` do? Is `correlate` an implementation of the previous algorithm with the double loop or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the links through to the page that explains the `logFilter` function, it appears to essentially be a correlation of the image with the following matrix as a kernel:

[image]

Which in R is

```r
LoG_kernel <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1,   2,   2,   2, 1, 1, 0, 
                       1, 2, 4,   5,   5,   5, 4, 2, 1, 
                       1, 4, 5,   3,   0,   3, 5, 4, 1, 
                       2, 5, 3, -12, -24, -12, 3, 5, 2, 
                       2, 5, 0, -24, -40, -24, 0, 5, 2, 
                       2, 5, 3, -12, -24, -12, 3, 5, 2, 
                       1, 4, 5,   3,   0,   3, 5, 4, 1, 
                       1, 2, 4,   5,   5,   5, 4, 2, 1, 
                       0, 1, 1,   2,   2,   2, 1, 1, 0), 9L)
```

However, your image sppears to be the Laplacian of the LoG. The Laplacian is the correlation of the image with this matrix:

```r
L_kernel <- matrix(c(-1, -1, -1,
                     -1,  8, -1, 
                     -1, -1, -1), 3L)
```

Furthermore, Haskell seems to truncate values to the 0, 1 range, meaning we need the following little helper function:

```r
truncate <- function(image) {
  image[image < 0] <- 0
  image[image > 1] <- 1
  image
}
```

That done, we can replicate your Haskell result with:

```r
library(imager)

load.image("Klein.png") |>
  correlate(as.cimg(LoG_kernel)) |> 
  correlate(as.cimg(L_kernel)) |>
  truncate() |>
  save.image("LLoG.png")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. That's doubly strange: in Haskell this is correlation, not a convolution, and with the **imager** package I also get a gray image if I use convolve. Will try **magick**.

Comment: That's not the same result. If you want you can try with [the original image](https://github.com/stla/HaskellImages/blob/main/images/Klein_Fibonacci_cm4_1024px.png).

Comment: I tried `image_morphology(method = "correlate"` but this function does not work on my laptop.

Comment: Ah it works with the kernel given as a string, like in the given example at the end.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, but it seems to give me the same result as the convolution

Comment: No, the result with the correlation has more "details".

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent For a symmetric kernel like the ones used in this example, correlation and convolution produce the same result. Correlation is a convolution with a mirrored kernel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok, thank you for the info. I've seen what you say in the Haskell code, indeed. I did a thousand mistakes with the pictures, I wasn't comparing the good ones. But we finally figured out.

Comment: Alan, one can also use the `imlap` function for the Laplacian.

Comment: @CrisLuengo might be nice to have diplib in R. It should be easy enough to provide R bindings to the C++ functions. Has anyone floated that idea before?

Comment: @AllanCameron Maybe 20 years ago someone asked about it. But at the time we didn’t know anyone willing to build that, or maintain it. If you’re willing to build it, and it’s not too complex for us to maintain, we’ll we be happy to accept it into the project!